# classic asp vbscript, retrieve SQL return value

Tags: sql, vbscript

I inherited an application which uses classic asp. How can I check the return v alue of a SQL query executed using ADOConnection?  I Modified an existing query to return 1 if a condition is not satisfied and would like to check for 0 (success) or 1 (failure) in the vbscript after calling rs.Open if possible.  Do I need to change the ADO connection to an ADOCommand?  Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide us with a little code to start with?  What exactly have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need define the return value as an ADOparameter in your code. and yes. you need use ADOCommand too.